# How to integrate a function over a circular loop?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields

I know this looks like a stupid question, but I want to know what I'm doing wrong here.

In the integral, the function itself is a scalar that does not depend on coordinates. The differential length element of the loop is the vector. I used the $R \cos{\theta}\hat{i} + R \sin{\theta}\hat{j}$ to define the circular loop, took its derivative for its differential length vector, giving $(-R \sin{\theta}\hat{i} + R \cos{\theta}\hat{j})d\theta$. Then integrated the function from $\theta = 0$ to $\theta = 2\pi$. The result was $0$, obviously.

I know for a fact that the integrated result should not be zero, since it represents a potential field from a current carrying conductor loop, measured at a distance away from the loop. The function is an AC current, i.e. $I_o\sin{2\pi ft}$.

Ideally, I want to know how to exactly integrate over a loop. What am I missing to get the right integral? I tried replacing $\cos{\theta}$ and $\sin{\theta}$ with actual ratio of triangle sides, but the value $\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}$ gives problems because of sign duality.

Edit: The actual integral I want to perform is:
$$\int_{\theta = 0}^{2\pi}{I_o\sin{(2\pi ft)}(-R \sin{\theta}\hat{i} + R \cos{\theta}\hat{j})d\theta}.$$ This is as described earlier in the question.

Comment: Can you include the actual integral that you are trying to evaluate as part of your post?

Comment: If your goal is to "add up the scalar function values on the loop, weighted by loop length", then you shouldn't be integrating a vector quantity. The "differential length" in your integral should be the *norm* of the vector you found.

Comment: @march, I added the exact expression, although it is the same as I described earlier. As I said, the integral seems wrong because it should be a non-zero value - it's a potential field of a current carrying conductor.

Comment: So, the current part doesn't matter, because it doesn't depend on $\theta$. For the rest, you can separate the integral into a sum of two integrals, one for the $\hat{i}$ component and one for the $\hat{j}$ component. Then, you are integrating sine or cosine over one period, so you get zero for each component.  So the integral as written down really is zero (this is why I asked for the clarification!). If you know it's not supposed to be zero, then you're missing something, like perhaps dotting the differential line element into the local vector potential.